# Vim autocmd for FileType not working indirectly

Tags: vim, neovim

I have a custom `~/.vimrc` I made with this `augroup`:

```
augroup filetype_vim
    autocmd!
    autocmd! BufWritePost .vimrc* source %
    autocmd FileType vim |
      setlocal foldlevel=0  foldmethod=marker foldmarker={{{,}}}
augroup END
```

When I open vim directly to edit the `~/.vimrc` like this: `vim ~/.vimrc`, the folding works as expected, I can fold `{{{` marker:

```
:set foldmethod?
> foldmethod=marker
```

When I open vim without specifying a file: `vim`, and then trying to edit: `:e ~/.vimrc`, the foldmethod is different!

```
:set foldmethod?
> foldmethod=syntax
```

Which obviously comes from a different part of my vimrc.

Why doesn't it recognizes the file type when I open the file indirectly?

Comment: I could reproduce this with my vimrc. But I found out that moving the augroup to the beginning of .vimrc, the behavior became as expected. The location seems relevant:only when the augroup definition is near the end of .vimrc, it does not work well.

Comment: I moved it to the top, still not working @ruud

Comment: same with me when it is exactly at the top. But if I move it down a bit, it starts working. Cannot explain why yet, but it is worth trying.

Comment: If you list the autocommands of the group, what does it says? /// PS: IMO the end-user is free to tell what is her/his preferred folding method (plugin/expression, indent, syntax), but when a file has markers, then user preferences are irrelevant. It's up to the file to clam: _"hey I'm meant to be folded with markers"_. That's why all my vim files tells how they want to be folded through their modeline.

Comment: @LucHermitte how do I list autocommands of the group?

Comment: @Moshe: `:verbose au {groupname}` -- without the curly brackets of course. `verbose` is not mandatory, but it'll give more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've failed with VimScript syntax. Must be

```
 autocmd FileType vim
  \ setlocal foldlevel=0  foldmethod=marker foldmarker={{{,}}}
```

What you did instead is

```
autocmd FileType vim <nothing> | <nothing>
setlocal foo bar
```

Therefore `setlocal` applies to the current buffer only (i.e. command-line argument), not to anything else.

Comment: So, what the pipe `|` is for?

Comment: @Moshe Vim is a modal editor which means every key hit does different things depending on context (mode). When you want to know what some "thing" does on the command-line you read help for "colon"-thing, i.e. `:h :bar`.

Comment: I meant, what does the pipe on the `autocmd` line does?

Comment: @Moshe I'm sorry to answer by asking a question, but have you really read `:h :bar`?

Comment: thanks now I understand, `autocmd` sees `|` as an argument. So if I want multiple `setlocal` on different lines, do I need to chain them with `|\n \ setlocal...` or just `\` is sufficient?

Comment: @Moshe There are many ways to do the same thing. If there's only one autocmd vs. multiple commands then you have to use both "bar" and "backslash"; if it's one autocmd and one command with a ton of arguments spread upon many lines then it's enough to use just backslashes; if it's multiple autocmds with one command per each then you probably don't need any, etc.

Comment: @Moshe But the most flexible way is to do simply `autocmd Event pattern source myfile` and put all commands into that file. In case of FileType event it's already done by a standard ftplugin, so it's highly recommended for everyone not to reinvent the wheel but put all your commands into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/vim.vim`. This way you don't need to trap FileType event yourself at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216123/discussion-between-moshe-and-matt).